# Get the tag name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let us say I have in HTML:

```
<input name="something" id="someid" />
```

And then in Jquery, I want to click on some element and after I click I want to get the tag name of the element.

So this.getTheTagName.

Everything I tried so far does not really work, especially for input tag.

Comment: `<input>` is an `EMPTY` element. The end tag is forbidden and it cannot have child nodes.

Comment: So how do I go about recognizing and retrieving the name INPUT? AND YES sorry, wrote that in a rush.

Comment: @user461316 I believe most comments are mostly seeking clarification so your question could be understood & answered better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably mean the `name` *attribute* and not the tag name.

```
alert($('#someid').attr('name'));
```

If you did mean the tag name, use `.prop('tagName')`:

```
alert($('#someid').prop('tagName'));
```

Here's an example for both: http://jsfiddle.net/wwQ7h/

Answer (score 7):

```
$('#someid').click( function() {
    alert( this.tagName );
});
```

Some browsers may not do the click event on input. Instead you might want `focus()`

```
$('#someid').focus( function() {
     alert( this.tagName);
});
```

Comment: As @Quentin said in his comment on your original post - your HTML is invalid. Though focus() may work better anyway. I'm editing my post

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo I made in a rush. That is not the problem.